# How to highlight the error field in form_tag with <div class="field_with_error">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to highlight my input field when error happens, I exactly know how to do it in form_for(rails do it). And i search it on google, it just tell me the field_error_proc things, but it seems that function doesn't work in form_tag and this is my code:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: :user, action: :change_password, id: current_user.id}, {method: :patch}) do %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>
  <h5>Old password:</h5>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Errors**

We achieved this using a somewhat hacky effort [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) (click "register" at top & try submitting without data):

```
#app/views/controller/your_form.erb
<%= form_tag ...... do %>
    <%= content_tag :div, @user.errors[:attribute], class: "error" if @user.errors[:attribute].present? %>
<% end %>
```

Every time you return an object to a view which has gone through validations, it should have an [`errors` object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) attached.

I'm not sure if this will work directly with `form_tag`, but I *do* know it works with `form_for` (something you may wish to look into). You should read up on the `ActiveModel::Errors` object which is attached to model objects when they come back from validation

--

**Implementation**

If you use the code I created above, it will basically allow you to show any errors that are assigned to your attributes, when they are present.

Most people will refer you to the `@object.errors.full_messages` method - which basically displays the entire messages for the errors you've received. These `full_messages` basically give you `attribute | message` - which means if you loop through the `errors` object, it *should* allow you to refer each attribute individually

As mentioned, you can see a demonstration of this idea in my link above!

Comment: yeah, I know that, and I can display the errors on my pages.But the I want to rails to highlight the html things. For example, if I put the wrong password the input's border will become red, which form_for can do.

Comment: For that, you'll have to look at `field_with_errors` - if you wish to replicate that in `form_for`, you'll have to use a conditional class to set whether the field has errors or not